# Linked list implemented as classes, not imperative code

Tags: c++, linked-list

As an update to [previous code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/9193/linked-list-review) I've submitted:

Improvements this time are mainly having everything moved to a class, before I plough on and add more functionality (I've come back to C++ after a few years away and this is a revision exercise).

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LinkedList.h"

class LinkedList
{
public:
    LinkedList(void);
    ~LinkedList(void);
    void traverseList();
    int length();
    void push(int data);

private:
    struct node{
    int data;
    node *pointee;
    };

    node *head;
    node *last;
    int count;
};

LinkedList::LinkedList(void)
{
        head = new node();
    last = new node();
    head->data = 0;
    head->pointee = last;
    last->data = 0;
    last->data = NULL;
    count = 2;
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList(void)
{
}

/*
    To be replaced with an iterator and an overloaded print operator for output
*/
void LinkedList::traverseList(){
    for(node *iterator = LinkedList::head ; iterator ; iterator = iterator->pointee)
    {
        std::cout << iterator->data << std::endl;
    }
}

int LinkedList::length(){
    return LinkedList::count;
}

void LinkedList::push(int data){

    node *newNode = new node();
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->pointee = NULL;
    last = newNode;
    ++count;
}

int main(){

    LinkedList list;

    for(int i=1 ; i<4 ; i++)
    {
        list.push(i);
    }

    int length = list.length();
    std::cout << length << std::endl;
    list.traverseList();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since we have no clean implementations:

The thing to notice is that the push_back() and erase() become trivial if you use a sentinal. This is because you do not need to test for NULL in any part of the code.

```
    Node(Node* after)
    {
        prev          = after;
        next          = after->next;
        prev->next    = this;
        next->prev    = this;
    }
    ~Node()
    {
        prev->next  = next;
        next->prev  = prev;
    }

    iterator push_back(T const& value)
    {
        tail    = new ValueNode(value, tail);

        // If new succeeded then increment count
        ++count;
        return iterator(tail);
    }

    void erase(iterator const& i)
    {
        // Get the value we will set as tail if the delete works
        Node*   newTail = (tail == i.node)
                            ? i.node->prev
                            : tail;
        delete i.node;
        // Delete worked now we can update the state.
        tail    = newTail;
        --count;
    }
```

Here is the whole code

```
#ifndef THORS_ANVIL_UTILITY_LINKED_LIST
#define THORS_ANVIL_UTILITY_LINKED_LIST

#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
class LinkedList
{
    struct Node
    {
        Node*   prev;
        Node*   next;
        Node(Node* after)
        {
            prev          = after;
            next          = after->next;
            prev->next    = this;
            next->prev    = this;
        }
        ~Node()
        {
            prev->next  = next;
            next->prev  = prev;
        }
        void swap(Node& rhs) throw()  { std::swap(prev, rhs.prev); std::swap(next, rhs.next);}
    };
    struct ValueNode: Node
    {
        ValueNode(T const& value, Node* after)
            : Node(after)
            , data(value)
        {}
        T       data;
    };

    Node    head;
    Node*   tail;
    int     count;

    public:
        struct Iterator: std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, T, ptrdiff_t, const T*, const T&>
        {
            Iterator(Node* node): node(node){}

            T&       operator*()        {return  static_cast<ValueNode*>(node)->data;}
            T*       operator->()       {return &static_cast<ValueNode*>(node)->data;}
            T const& operator*()  const {return  static_cast<ValueNode*>(node)->data;}
            T const* operator->() const {return &static_cast<ValueNode*>(node)->data;}

            Iterator& operator++()     /*prefix*/  { node = node->next; return *this;}
            Iterator& operator--()     /*prefix*/  { node = node->prev; return *this;}
            Iterator  operator++(int)  /*postfix*/ { Iterator result(*this);this->operator++(); return result;}
            Iterator  operator--(int)  /*postfix*/ { Iterator result(*this);this->operator--(); return result;}

            bool operator !=(Iterator const& rhs) const    { return node != rhs.node;}
            bool operator ==(Iterator const& rhs) const    { return !(*this != node);}

            mutable Node*   node;
        };

        LinkedList()
            : tail(&head)
            , count(0)
        {}

        ~LinkedList()
        {
            clear();
        }

        void clear()
        {
            while(head.next != &head)
            {
                Node*   old = head.next;
                head.next   = head.next->next;
                --count;
                delete old;
            }
        }

        LinkedList(LinkedList const& copy)
            : tail(&head)
            , count(0)
        {
            std::for_each(copy.head->next, copy.head, std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&LinkedList::push_back), this));
        }
        LinkedList& operator=(LinkedList rhs)
        {
            rhs.swap(*this);
            return *this;
        }
        void swap(LinkedList& rhs) throw()
        {
            std::swap(head,     rhs.head);
            std::swap(tail,     rhs.tail);
            std::swap(count,    rhs.count);
        }

        bool    isEmpty()   const { return &head == tail; }
        size_t  size()      const { return count; }

        typedef Iterator           iterator;
        typedef Iterator const     const_iterator;

        iterator push_back(T const& value)
        {
            tail    = new ValueNode(value, tail);
            ++count;
            return iterator(tail);
        }

        void erase(iterator const& i)
        {
            Node*   newTail = (tail == i.node)
                                ? i.node->prev
                                : tail;
            tail    = newTail;
            --count;
            delete i.node;
        }

        iterator begin()                {return iterator(head.next);}
        const_iterator begin() const    {return iterator(head.next);}
        iterator end()                  {return iterator(&head);}
        const_iterator end() const      {return iterator(&head);}
};
#endif
```

Then Main

```
#include <LinkedList.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    LinkedList<int> list;
    list.push_back(5);
    LinkedList<int>::iterator item = list.push_back(7);
    for(LinkedList<int>::iterator loop = list.begin(); loop != list.end(); ++loop)
    {
        std::cout << *loop << "\n";
    }
    list.erase(item);
    for(LinkedList<int>::iterator loop = list.begin(); loop != list.end(); ++loop)
    {
        std::cout << *loop << "\n";
    }
}
```

### Diagram of Node Insertion:

#### Node Before Insertion Starts

```
      after                                        
      #########                         #########   
   -->#  Next #------------------------>#  Next #----
      #       #                         #       #
   ---#Prev   #<------------------------#Prev   #<---
      #########                         #########    

                       NewNode(this)
                       #########
                       #   Next#
                       #Prev   #
                       #########
```

#### prev          = after;

```
      after
      #########                         #########   
   -->#  Next #------------------------>#  Next #----
      #       #                         #       #
   ---#Prev   #<------------------------#Prev   #<---
      #########   |                     #########    
                  |
                  |    (this)
                  |    #########
                  |    #   Next#
                  -----#Prev   #
                       #########
```

#### next          = after->next;

```
      after
      #########                         #########   
   -->#  Next #------------------------>#  Next #----
      #       #                  |      #       #
   ---#Prev   #<-----------------|------#Prev   #<---
      #########   |              |       #########    
                  |              |
                  |    (this)    |
                  |    ######### |
                  |    #   Next#--
                  -----#Prev   #
                       #########
```

#### prev->next    = this;

```
      after
      #########                         #########   
   -->#  Next #------            ------>#  Next #----
      #       #     |            |      #       #
   ---#Prev   #<----|------------|------#Prev   #<---
      #########   | |            |      #########    
                  | |            |
                  | |  (this)    |
                  | |  ######### |
                  | -->#   Next#--
                  -----#Prev   #
                       #########
```

#### next->prev    = this;

```
      after
      #########                         #########   
   -->#  Next #------            ------>#  Next #----
      #       #     |            |      #       #
   ---#Prev   #<--- |            |   ---#Prev   #<---
      #########   | |            |   |  #########    
                  | |            |   |
                  | |  (this)    |   |
                  | |  ######### |   |
                  | -->#   Next#--   |
                  -----#Prev   #<-----
                       #########
```

Comment: Could you please explain why you assign next->prev to this and not after in the constructor? It's the only but of the code, I don't understand, even after drawing pictures.

Comment: @TomKealy: Hope that helps

Comment: :O Thanks! I read the code as if you were inserting after between this and prev and thought it didn't make sense. Awesome pics.

Answer (score 5):

You have a problem with your constructor and `push()` method.

When you create a new linked list, you automatically create two new nodes - head and last.  This means you can't have an empty linked list as every new linked list will have 2 nodes in it.  This isn't what I'd expect a linked list to do; I'd expect a new linked list to have a count of 0 and for both head and last to point to `NULL`.

When I add an item using `push()`, the class does this:

```
last = newNode
```

However, because `last` was set to a new node struct in the constructor, the class just lost any reference to the existing `last` memory and caused a memory leak.  Another issue you've got is you're not actually creating a trail from node to node: you never set the `pointee` property of the previously-last node.

The `push()` method should look something like this:

```
void LinkedList::push(int data){
    node *newNode = new node();
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->pointee = NULL;

    if (!head) {
        head = newNode;
        last = newNode;
    } else {
        last->pointee = newNode;
        last = newNode;
    }

    ++count;
}
```

The constructor should look like this:

```
LinkedList::LinkedList(void)
{
    head = NULL;
    last = NULL;
    count = 0;
}
```

You aren't cleaning anything up the destructor so you're leaking all allocated nodes.  The destructor should look something like this:

```
LinkedList::~LinkedList(void)
{
    node* current = head;
    node* next;

    while (current) {
        next = current->pointee;
        delete current;
        current = next;
    }
}
```

Finally, I'd suggest capitalising `node` to `Node`.

Comment: Most Liked list implementations use a head a tail terminator nodes to make the rest of the code easier to write (see your implementation of push() it could be half the length if you know head and tail are never NULL), so normally I would expect head and tail never to be NULL (though they should not be part of the count as they are not real nodes (they are just there to mark the ends)).

Comment: Though I also make type names always have a capitol letter first (as in Node) it is hard to make this an overall recommendation as the standard libraries do not use this convention see std::vector, std::map etc.

Comment: @Loki: Interesting.  Having terminator head and tail nodes would make a function that returned the actual tail an O(n) operation.

Comment: I agree, Ant. I've implemented lists with iterator classes and I've always used `null` as the 'end' in the iterator. Also, Loki, I don't think STL and std:: conventions should dictate how any library's conventions should be written. If anything, I much prefer to use CamelCase as it appears more modern and formal. That's my style though.

Comment: @Ant: I see no reason why this would make it an O(n) operation. I think you are assuming both head and tail terminator need to be different for some reason. This is not the case.

Comment: @Nick Bedford: I agree (Which as you may note above is what I said). But neither would I recommend another way that is just as stylistic a recommendation which was my point if you read closely.

Comment: @NickBedford: Using null as the terminator doubles the amount of code you need to write. The standard way of implementing this is to have a fake terminator node.

Comment: Well, you would likely "cache" the null iterator and just return that in `end()` for `i != end()`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in implementing some basic containers, it would be wise to learn about templates. Not only does this remove the need to have multiple copies for anything other than `int`, it also removes the need for a separate .cpp implementation file.

The Standard Template Library (STL) is a mass of template based classes and as a result, they can be used with basically any type of data.

```
template<class T>
class List
{
private:
    class Node
    {
        T value;
        Node *next;
        Node *previous;

        Node(const T &data)
            : value(data) { }
    };

    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
    int count;

public:
    List()
        : head(0), tail(0), count(0) { }

    List(const List &list)
        : head(0), tail(0), count(0)
    {
        // Assuming an iterator implementation, copy values
        for(Iterator i = list.Begin(); i != End(); i++)
            Append(*i);
    }

    List &operator =(const List &list)
    {
        List l(list);
        std::swap(head, l.head);
        std::swap(tail, l.tail);
        std::swap(count, l.count);
    }

    ~List()
    {
        Clear();
    }

    void Clear()
    {
        while(head)
        {
            Node *next = head->next;
            delete head;
            head = next;
        }
        count = 0;
        head = tail = 0;
    }

    void Append(const T &data)
    {
        Node *node = new Node(data);
        if (!head)
        {
            node->next = node->previous = 0;
            head = tail = node;
        }
        else
        {
            node->previous = tail;
            tail->next = node;
            node->next = 0;
            tail = node;
        }
        count++;
    }

    int Count() const
    {
        return count;
    }
};
```

After fully implementing the different functions needed for a functional doubly-linked list, you can use it in code like this.

```
List<float> numbers;
numbers.Append(1.23f);

List<std::string> strings;
strings.Append("Hello, world!");
```

Comment: If you are going to implement the CopyConstructor (rather than disable) you should also add the assignment operator (see rule of 3/5). To save you I have added one.

Comment: I find the comment `it also removes the need for a separate .cpp implementation file` grossly misleading. It does not need to be a template for you to put all the code in the header file nor even if it is a template does not require you to put everything into the header file. In-fact I would suggest that non trivial template class are split into declaration and definition (just like normal code) so that the interface is easy to read (how you include it in the project is different (you use a .tpp or .tcc file that is included from the header). Check the standard library for examples.

Comment: To be fair, I was only providing an example of templated code, so there's many things that I haven't included in the example. Operator overloads, copy constructors etc. But for me, I've never heard of templates being split into declaration and definition (besides specialisations), despite writing and looking at many templated classes. Just never come across it myself. That being said, I've tried reading STL code and I find it a chore to read because of the coding conventions used (personal opinion).

Comment: I just looked at your assignment operator. I'm not sure how copying some pointers around will assign a List<T> to another List<T>. I would for intents and purposes expect (and functionally require) a copy of the nodes to be made for both lists to work independently.

Comment: An assignment operator should copy (assign) the values. Swapping doesn't seem like a logical conclusion in an assignment operator...

Comment: To be fair when you post code you should make sure it works. This code is broken in that it does not obey the rule of three/five. When your class contains raw pointers (even in examples you must either disable both or implement both copy constructor and assignment operator. Leaving broken code for inexperienced users on a site like this is a very bad idea.

Comment: Then you should look up the copy and swap idiom (as I noted in the comments). Notice that the parameter passed is by value providing the copy part of the idiom the swap is then applied. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom best answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3279616/14065

Comment: Thank you for providing the assignment operator. But that is a really **bad** implementation (its not exception safe), Please learn the copy and swap idiom (or how to implement an exception safe assignment **AND** Clear). This is the kind of thing we look for when hiring programers.

Comment: Overall: just acceptable. but not good enough for a +1 as you provide nothing really us full to the OP.

Comment: You didn't implement the *copy* part of copy-and-swap, so your example made no sense to me. You were simply swapping pointers between the lhs and rhs. I've re-implemented C&S.

Comment: I did; you just did not see it. Your implementation is getting better. BUT you have implemented copy and swap the old way (by actually making a temporary). By passing the parameter by value (rather than reference) you get an implicit copy (the modern way of doing it). As it turns out using the pass by value technique helps the compiler spot RVO optimizations and as such is the preferred technique to implement copy and swap idiom. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034635/explicit-copy-constructor-or-implicit-parameter-by-value

Comment: Now all you have to do is fix Clear() so that it is exception safe! :-)

Comment: I stand corrected. I'm curious, do you have any books or references that would point me to more of these very specific implementation idioms?

Comment: See: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq