# Make LinkedList in C++ more clean

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have been working on a linked list for some while now and started out with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141477/simple-linked-list-c).

Is my code clean? Or is there some way to make it better and more readable?

The reason for this question is for me to be a better programmer. I would love to get one step further for making more clean code.

my class:

```
using namespace std;

class Node
{

public:
    int nX; 
    Node *next;
    //constructor
    Node(){ head = NULL; }          //Initialising head to NULL
    void addValueLeft(int nVal);
    void addValueRight(int nVal);
    void deleteValueLeft();
    void deleteValueRight();
    void printList();
private:
    Node *head;   //a pointer to the first Node
};
```

my main:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    using namespace std;
    //creating a new object
    Node list;

    list.addValueLeft(5);
    list.addValueLeft(6);
    list.addVaueRight(8);
    list.deleteValueRight();
    list.printList();

    return 0;
}
```

my functions:

```
    void Node::addValueLeft(int nVal)
    {
        Node *newNode = new Node;
        if(!head)
        {
            newNode->nX = nVal;
            newNode->next = NULL;
            head = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            newNode->nX = nVal;
            newNode->next = head;
            head = newNode;
        }
    }

    void Node::printList()
    {
        if(!head)       //list is empty - nothing to print
        {
            //cout << "nothing to print - list empty " << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            Node *tempNode = new Node;
            tempNode = head;
            while(tempNode)
            {
                cout << tempNode-> nX << endl;
                tempNode = tempNode->next;
            }
        }
    }

    void Node::addValueRight(int nVal)
    {
        Node *tempNode1 = new Node;

        if(!head)                   //List is empty
        {
            tempNode1 -> nX   = nVal;
            tempNode1 -> next = head;
            head = tempNode1;
        }
        else
        {
            tempNode1 = head;
            while(tempNode1 -> next != NULL)        //Go to last Node
            {
                tempNode1 = tempNode1->next;

            }
            Node *tempNode2 = new Node;         //create temp node
            tempNode2 -> nX = nVal;
            tempNode2 -> next = NULL;
            tempNode1 -> next = tempNode2;   //tempNode1 will be last Node    
    }
    }


    void Node::deleteValueLeft()
    {
        if(!head)       //list is empty - Nothing to Delete
        {
            //cout << " deleteValueLeft:  Nothing to delete" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            head = head->next;
        }
    }

    void Node::deleteValueRight()
    {
        if(head == NULL)    //Nothing to delete
        {
            //cout << "Nothing to delete " << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            Node *tempNode1 = new Node;
            Node *oldNode = new Node;
            tempNode1 = head;
            if(tempNode1->next == NULL) //only one element
            {
                head = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                while(tempNode1->next!=NULL)        //Go to last Node
                {
                    oldNode = tempNode1;
                    tempNode1 = tempNode1->next;

                }
                oldNode->next = NULL;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: If you use a `Sentinal` it makes the creation of a linked list a lot easier to write and the code a lot cleaner. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/9399/507

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's some feedback (not an exhaustive list).

```
using namespace std;
```

Please stop doing this. when you add `using namespace` directives in header files, any file including that header will have potential namespace clashes (which is the problem namespaces are trying to prevent).

```
class Node
{
public:
    int nX; // (1)
    Node *next; // (2)
    Node(){ head = NULL; }  // (3)
```

Notes:

The only ways lines (1) and (2) are acceptable, are:

- if instances of your class are valid regardless what you place in nX and next.

Client code example:

```
Node n;
n.nX = 1001; // is this valid?
n.next = n; // is this valid?
```

- if Node class is moved from the global namespace to the private section of another class. That way, the outer class will protect the node's data.

Otherwise, nX and next should be private data, with getters to read the values and setters to validate and set the values.

Line (3) is a bad implementation for a constructor, because it leaves a new instance in a partially-initialized state (it should initialize nX, next and head, explicitly and in this specific order).

Better implementation:

```
explicit Node(int value = 0): nX(value), next(nullptr), head(nullptr) {}
```

Note regarding class API design:

You are implementing both a node (for an element of the list) and a list of nodes. You should have two classes instead of one, and the `head` pointer should be a member of the list, not a node:

```
class Node {
    int nX; Node* next;
public:
    // ... rest of node interface here
};

class List {
    Node *head;
public:
    List() {}
    const std::size_t size() const;
    void add_value_end(int value);
    // ... rest of interface here
};
```

Eventually, you should consider using node as an internal structure of the list:

```
class List {
    class Node { /* same as above */ };
    Node *head;
public:
    // same as above
};
```

Comment: Implementing a linked list without a dummy head node should be very, very high on the list of "do nots" in my opinion. Just means the code needs tons of special cases for no good reason.

Comment: @Voo, can you please be more specific? My proposed  implementation doesn't require (or impose) a dummy head, nor special cases in processing (as far as I can tell). Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Implement the usual functions (add, remove, search,..) on a double linked list twice. Once assume that an empty list has `head = nullptr`  and the second time that `head` is always a valid dummy node (which if the list is empty points to itself). You'll see that the later results in much nicer code.

Comment: I just tried writing an append method for the list and saw what you mean: an implementation with a dummy head, will ensure that in the situations where you implement iteration (`Node *p = head; while(p->next) ...`) you don't need to check the validity of the iterator before accessing 'next'.

Comment: Exactly. It's one of those tricks when working with data structures that makes reasoning about them (and implementing) easier. Very useful trick to have in your toolbox.

Comment: If you're going to do `Node(int value=0)`... you really _must_ make it an explicit constructor - `explicit Node(int value=0)` - or you will create an implicit casting between your list node and its payload and you do not want that. In fact, in general, you should get in the habit of _always_ putting `explicit` in front of single parameter constructors unless you really, really want casting.

Comment: so instead of _using_ _namespace_ _std_ , I should use _std::cout_ etc?

Comment: Either use `std::cout`, or place `using std::cout;` in the functions where you use std::cout. Same for other std:: symbols. Worst case, you can place `using namespace std;` in the body of various functions. The point is to not put it globally (not in cpp and especially not in header files).

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @utnapistim answer, that you should have two classes: a `List` class with a `head` element, and a `Node` class with a `next` element.

As well:

- The `if` in your `addValueLeft` is unecessary: you do the same thing (i.e. you assign the same value to `nX`, `next`, and `head`) no matter what the `if` value is.
- In `addValueRight` you should not have two `new Node;` statements: you are leaking the first new node.
- You should have a `List` destructor which deletes all the nodes on the list
- Your `deleteValue` methods should delete the node before forgetting about it; for example:

  ```
  void Node::deleteValueLeft()
  {
      if(!head)
          return; //list is empty - Nothing to Delete
      Node* firstNode = head;
      head = head->next;
      // you weren't doing the following;
      // note that I get/dereference head->next before I delete this old head
      delete firstNode; 
  }
  ```
- Perhaps your Node should have a non-default constructor; because a Node is only created when there's a value to store in it:

Answer (score 4):

Well, there are many problems in the code. Does this compile and run correctly? Some things I have noticed:

- Make the member variables in `Node` private as they are not needed outside. And if they were, you should probably provide getter and setter methods.
- The member variable `Node::head` should be `static` because the head is ALWAYS the same. The way you are doing it now each instance of Node (so each Node) has its own `head`. This is not only waste of memory but also wrong.  With `static` there is only *one* instance of `Node *head` in the memory. (Of course in that case you must not set `head` to `NULL`). Notice that this solution has the disadvantage that you can only have one list at a time. But to solve this there are only two possibilities:

  1. Leave it non static. But then you have to adjust the member variable in each node once the head changes (very costly). Moreover (as mentioned above) you waste memory.
  2. As suggested by the other answers: make two classes. A class for the `List` and a (nested) class for the node. The `head` pointer is then a member of the `List` (not the `Node` anymore). This way you can instantiate many `List`s with different `head`s.

The latter is obviously the better solution an is the common way to solve that problem.

So `Node` should/could be changed to be like that:(here `head` is static)

```
class Node
{
public:
     Node();              //Do NOT initialize to NULL
private:
    int nX; 
    Node *next;
    static Node *head = NULL;// initialize to NULL
};
```

Another thing that is seen as better practice is to use initialization lists (read about it). In short:
An initialization list initializes (as the name suggests) variables on construction.

And many other things. Including but not limited to the following:

```
  void Node::addValueLeft(int nVal)
{
    Node *newNode = new Node;

    newNode->nX = nVal;
    newNode->next = head;  // set to old head. If head is NULL, it is OK, too.
    if(!head)              // if list is empty, make head pointing at the new node
        head = newNode;
}

void Node::printList()
{
    // if is unnecessary here. If list is empty the while loop
    // is skipped anyway.

    Node *tempNode = head; // no new Node here
    while(tempNode)
    {
        cout << tempNode-> nX << endl;
        tempNode = tempNode->next;
    }
}

void Node::addValueRight(int nVal)
{
    Node *tempNode1; // no good naming and no need for new Node

    Node *tempNode2 = new Node; //create temp node
    tempNode2 -> nX = nVal;
    tempNode2 -> next = NULL;

    if(head == NULL){           // if list is empty, the new Node is the first Node
        head = tempNode2;
    }else{                      // if there are Nodes in the list ...
        tempNode1 = head;
        while(tempNode1 -> next != NULL)  // ... Go to last Node
        {
            tempNode1 = tempNode1->next;
        }
        tempNode1 -> next = tempNode2;    //tempNode2 will be last Node
    }
}
```

I would really like to help more but I think you have to read more about the basics. Most important: read much much much about pointers. Moreover read about `new` and `delete`.
If you have more (specific) questions feel free to ask.

Comment: +1; but `head` cannot be static if there is more than one List in the program.

Comment: A static `head` member in the Node class is so wrong that you should edit it out of your answer entirely.

Comment: @Peter on the one hand you are right. But on the other hand it is much better than the solution from the OP. But I will think about it and edit my answer to something more secure.

Comment: @exilit The OPs code may not be great but at least correct (ok, there's at least a *chance* it may be correct at least). Making the head node static on the other hand is a bug in any way you think about it.

Comment: @Voo I disagree. It is not a bug at all. The way this linked list is designed it is very obvious that there couldn't be multiple instances of that list. So is it a limitation? definitely! Is it poor design? It is! But is it a bug? no, it is not, because it works the way it is expected to. (statically it works just fine)

Comment: Well it's either a horrible bug in the implementation or a horrible bug in the specification (a datastructure where you can only ever have a single instance of is nigh useless) - however you look at it, there's a bug.

Comment: @Voo I agree with you that there is a flaw somewhere, I wouldn't usually call a flaw in the specification a "bug".

Comment: Putting a pointer to the head in a node is just plain bad design (since it prevents many of the operations that make lists worthwhile speedily). Doing it statically is even worse (since it limits you to one list in your whole program!).

Comment: This is codereview.  When there's a major architectural issue, recommend fixing the architecture, not a band-aid that will NEVER lead to a good design or clean code review.

Comment: @Peter You are totally right. But my aim was to modify HIS code so that he can identify what he has done himself and notice the differences (mistakes) more easy. Of course it is important to show him also the "right" way (as I have tried in the [initial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141477/simple-linked-list-c/22141970#22141970) discussion). This is the reason why utnapistim's answer is rated so high. Because this is the "best" practice but it's more difficult for the OP to understand because he lacks the basics. (But nonetheless +1 for utnapistim's nice answer).

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the problems with the code itself as pointed out in the other answers, I would like to comment on your interface naming. There are a few common names for linked list operations that any experienced programmer will expect:

- `push` / `pop` for stacks (first in, last out): Add an element to the end of the list, or remove the last added element from the end of the list
- `queue`/ `dequeue` for queues (first in, first out lists): Add an element to the start of the list and remove one from the end of the list.
- `shift` / `unshift` - I am not sure how common these terms are, but for example PHP uses this as the analog to `push` and `pop` for operations on the start of the list.