# A linked list with push pop append and destructor

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, reinventing-the-wheel

I tried to implement a linked list that can do pop(), push(), append(), printall(), and so on, and also I tried to handle the wraparound features, and de-wrap it when check if the list is cyclic to avoid endless loop, but I am sure this wrap and de-wrap features can be implemented better...

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node{
    int value;
    Node* next;
};

class LinkedList{

    std::size_t count;
    Node* head;

    public: 
    void pop();           //pop from head
    void push(int);       //push from head
    void append(int);     //append at end
    void wraparound();    //wrap around the list
    bool isCyclicDwrap(); //check if cyclic, if yes, de-wrap-around it

    void printll() const; 
    std::size_t size() const { return count; }

    LinkedList(): head(nullptr),count(0) {}
    ~LinkedList();
};


void LinkedList::pop(){

  if(head==nullptr){
    std::cout<<"empty stack !"<<std::endl;
    exit(0);
  }

  Node* cur = head;
  Node* tmp = cur->next;
  head = tmp;
  delete cur; count--;

}

void LinkedList::append(int data){
    Node* cur = head;
    Node* tmp = new Node;
    tmp->value = data;
    tmp->next = nullptr;

    if(!cur){
        head = tmp; count++;
    }
    else{
        while(cur->next != nullptr){
            cur = cur->next;
        }
        cur->next = tmp; count++;
    }

}

void LinkedList::wraparound(){
    Node* cur =head;
    while(cur->next != nullptr)
        cur=cur->next;

    cur->next = head;
}

bool LinkedList::isCyclicDwrap()
{
    Node *n1, *n2;
    n1 = head;
    n2 = head->next;

    do{
        n1 = n1->next;
        n2 = n2->next->next;

        if(n1 == n2){

            Node* cur =head;
            size_t cnt=count;
            while(--cnt != 0)
                cur=cur->next; //move to the last node
            cur->next=nullptr; // -> de-warp-around !

            return true;
        }

    }while(n1 != head);

    return false;
}


void LinkedList::push(int data)
{
    Node* cur = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    cur->value=data;
    cur->next=head;
    count++;
    head=cur;
}


void LinkedList::printll() const{
    if(head==nullptr)
        std::cout<<"empty Linkedlist!"<<std::endl;
    Node* cur = head;
    while(cur != nullptr){
        std::cout << cur->value << '\n';
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    Node* cur = head;

    while (cur != NULL)
    {
        Node* next = cur->next;
        delete cur;
        cur = next;
    }

    head = NULL;
}


int main(){
    LinkedList LL;
    LL.append(5);
    LL.append(6);
    LL.append(7);
    LL.printll();
    std::cout<<"size of the stack/linkedlist: "<<LL.size()<<std::endl;

    LL.wraparound();
    std::cout<<"Cyclic: "<<LL.isCyclicDwrap()<<"; if 1, then remove the Cyclic feauture!"<<std::endl;

    LL.push(4); //push
    LL.printll();
    std::cout<<"size of the stack/linkedlist: "<<LL.size()<<std::endl;

    LL.pop();
    LL.printll();
    std::cout<<"size of the stack/linkedlist: "<<LL.size()<<std::endl;

    LL.pop();
    LL.printll();
    std::cout<<"size of the stack/linkedlist: "<<LL.size()<<std::endl;

    LL.pop();
    LL.printll();
    std::cout<<"size of the stack/linkedlist: "<<LL.size()<<std::endl;

    LL.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without reading too far.

You have committed the biggest C++ sin possible. You have an owned pointer in your class and don't follow the rule of three (or five).

```
class LinkedList{

    std::size_t count;
    Node* head;          // This is an owned pointer.
```

You must implement the rule of three. Otherwise the following will cause you to blow up:

```
{
    LinkedList     list1;
    list1.push(5);

    LinkedList     list2(list1); // Copy construction.
}
// Both list go out of scope here and are destroyed.
// Both object have the same value for `head` and both destructors
// will destroy all the elements in that chain. You are going to have
// multiple double deletes.

// Same problem happens with assignment operator.
```

Comment: Thank you for the comments! could you spent some effort in providing a "standard" implementation of the linkedlist class with the rule of three(five), I suppose that would be very useful for other people as well:0

Comment: @lorniper: PS. If you implement the copy constructor the assignment operator can be easily implemented using the `copy and swap idiom`.

Comment: @lorniper: Have a look here: [Linked list implemented as classes, not imperative code](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/9399/507)

Answer (score 3):

I see a few things that could improve your code quite a bit:

**Linked List Structure Design**

You declare your `Node` structure outside of your `LinkedList` class in the header file; this means that anyone including the header file can access your `Node` structure and use it in their code. This is bad OO design since the `Node` structure is really an *implementation detail* of the `LinkedList`. Therefore, the user should be able to use the linked list without ever having to use (or the ability to use) the `Node` data structure. To fix this issue, I would declare the `Node` data structure inside of the private space of your `LinkedList` class. Moreover, I would provide a constructor for the `Node` data structure that will populate the values of the structure for me:

```
class LinkedList {
    struct Node {
        int data;
        Node *next;
        Node(int d, Node *n = nullptr) :
            data(d), next(n) {}
    }* head;
};
```

In this way, I can use the more C++ way of initializing objects on the heap over the more C way of doing things.

C++ way (recommended):

```
Node *node = new Node(data);
```

More C-style way (deprecated / not recommended):

```
Node *node = new Node();
node->data = data;
node->next = nullptr;
```

**Use C++ Style**

Speaking of C and C++ ways, do NOT mix `new` and `malloc` in C++ code - especially when you're using `delete` to free objects allocated by both. `new` and `delete` call constructors/destructors whereas `malloc` and `free` don't. Use `delete` to free `new`'d objects and `free` to free `malloc`'d objects. This code is invalid and can cause issues:

```
void LinkedList::push(int data)
{
    Node* cur = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    cur->value=data;
    cur->next=head;
    count++;
    head=cur;
}
```

Why not use the more C++ way of doing things:

```
void LinkedList::push(int data)
{
    Node* cur = new Node(data, head); // use constructor I defined for you above.
    ++count;
    head = cur;
}
```

In addition, keep your style consistent between `NULL` and `nullptr`. In C++11 and beyond, always prefer to use `nullptr`.

**Linked List API**

I would rename some of your functions to be a bit more descriptive. For example, I would make `wraparound()` be called `make_cyclic()`. I would also provide a counter function called `make_acyclic()` to break the cycle. To check for a cycle, I would rename your function to `is_cyclic()`. I would also add another function `is_empty()` to signal when the list is empty and a `size()` function to return the size of your list so far; otherwise, what's the point of the `count` member variable? There is also the added benefit that the `empty()` member function could clear up a bunch of bugs in your code:

**Bugs**

In your `wraparound()` and `isCyclicDwrap()` functions, you don't check for the case when the list is empty (when the head is pointing to `nullptr`). If the list is empty, derefrencing `nullptr` like this:

```
Node* cur = head;
while(cur->next)
```

is a segmentation fault error waiting to happen. The fix is to check if the list is empty before doing such operations.

Finally, I find your implementation of making the list acyclic (if it is cyclic) a little too heavy and breaks the principle that functions should only have one purpose. We could do something like this to split the two ideas of checking for a cycle and breaking one:

```
bool LinkedList::is_cyclic() const
{
    if (is_empty()) {
        return false;
    }

    Node *n1 = head, *n2 = head->next;
    while (n1 != n2) {
        if (!n2 || !n2->next) {
            return false;
        }
        n1 = n1->next;
        n2 = n2->next->next;
    }
    return true;
}

void LinkedList::make_acyclic()
{
    if (is_empty() || !is_cyclic()) {
        return;
    }

    Node *curr = head;
    while (curr->next != head) { // move to the end
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    curr->next = nullptr; // break the cycle
}
```

**Simplify Some Functions**

With the newly defined `Node` constructor, `append()` can become:

```
void LinkedList::append(int data){

    if(!head){
        head = new Node(data);
    }
    else{
        Node *cur = head;
        while (cur->next){
            cur = cur->next;
        }
        cur->next = new Node(data);
    }
    ++count;
}
```

Comment: Why use two lines: `Node* cur = new Node(data, head);head = cur;` When one will do `head = new Node(data, head);`